# How to Repeat Invoice for each company with stimulreport

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

I am using `StimulSoft` for my report in asp.net with c# language.
I have a report with 3 list, one as Head list and two other list for detail.
It's a bill report for range of date.
The problem is that I can't repeat them in order I like;
the following is the list and report I want :

```
HaedList >> BillId,Coname,TotalPrice,InvoiceDate
ServiceList >> BillId,ServiceName,ServiceCost
ProductList >> BillId,ProductName,ProductCost
```

The user will enter a date range, for example 2015/01/01 to 2015/01/03

```
--> Page 1

BillId=52 ---- CoName=Haaret

ServiceName=Repair,ServiceCost=12$
ServiceName=Cleaning,ServiceCost=2$

ProductName=DVD,ProductCost=10$
ProductName=CPU,ProductCost=60$
ProductName=VGA,ProductCost=40$

TotalPrice=124$
Tax=4$
Total >> 120$

--> Page 2
BillId=55 ---- CoName=GirBold

ServiceName=Training,ServiceCost=300$

ProductName=Pen,ProductCost=5$
ProductName=NoteBooks,ProductCost=10$

TotalPrice=315$
Tax=4$
Total >> 311$

--> Page 3

BillId=70---- CoName=DrillPort

ServiceName=Driver,ServiceCost=30$
ServiceName=Test,ServiceCost=10$

ProductName=Battery,ProductCost=35$
ProductName=Monitors,ProductCost=200$

TotalPrice=275$
Tax=4$
Total >> 271$
```

So I have 3 days in range, and I should print 4 pages in the following order.
My problem is that the head repeats three times then All service Printed, and then product, and then the summary from head, like the following:

```
BillId=52 ---- CoName=Haaret
BillId=70---- CoName=DrillPort
BillId=55 ---- CoName=GirBold


ServiceName=Repair,ServiceCost=12$
ServiceName=Cleaning,ServiceCost=2$
ServiceName=Driver,ServiceCost=30$
ServiceName=Test,ServiceCost=10$
ServiceName=Training,ServiceCost=300$

ProductName=DVD,ProductCost=10$
ProductName=CPU,ProductCost=60$
ProductName=VGA,ProductCost=40$
ProductName=Pen,ProductCost=5$
ProductName=NoteBooks,ProductCost=10$
ProductName=Battery,ProductCost=35$
ProductName=Monitors,ProductCost=200$

TotalPrice=124$
Tax=4$
Total >> 120$
TotalPrice=315$
Tax=4$
Total >> 311$
TotalPrice=275$
Tax=4$
Total >> 271$
```

The following link contains three Image and Report Template I have made for my project.

[The Sample and Three Image](http://karmozd.com/dl/ups/TemplateAndmages.zip)

Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried official forums at http://forum.stimulsoft.com/? There you have better chances to have a response

Comment: Yes , But they did not answer me , I also Mail to their support , I post a new topic and they deleted my post , I think that is because I am from IRAN.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `BillId` and `CoName` in **Group Header** and `ServiceName`,`ServiceCost`,`ProductName`,`ProductCost` in **Data** and `TotalPrice`,`Tax` and `Total` in **Group Footer**.

I do not have stimula in my system, but from template it seems that you did not have any Group Header or footer.

Also check that you send a correct query(with correct `group by`) to the report data source.

Comment: I sent three list to Stimul , I didn't know how to make relationship between them in Stimul , Also I don't know how to create a report for these three list in a page to repeat if Header list have more than one row. thanks.

Comment: Eghbal, Do you put group header in your report?
How you send 3 list to the Stimul. Just create one list that is result of sql query(or Linq or what ever...) and in that query use group by

Comment: I must sent three list , please read question complete. You should have Stimul and then see my template to get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually easy.

Convert ("parse") your data into a native .net dataset (i.e. like http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset) and use that to generate your report, by importing the dataset directly.

This has the benefit that can use T-SQL and/or link to manipulate the data in the dataset before the report generation. You can add an index column in the dataset which while it can be used for indexing internally, it can be "hidden" from the final report.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Master-Detail report. You could learn how to create it on [the Stimulsoft Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/getting_started_master-detail_report.htm).

Comment: Sorry but you did not my question complete. I have three list , in that help you send it just has a Title , and a list of product under that category. If you download my file I uploaded , you will get what I mean.

Comment: Unfortunately your link is not useful for me , because I have mixed three list that is so customized , if you download my files which I uploaded them here,you will see that its not simple. if you can please download my files and tell me what should I do. Thanks

Comment: Each Data Band should have one of the previous bands as Master. In your case this will be Master-detail-detail or Master with 2 details report. All Data Sources must have relations, that you should use as in User Manual. Follow the instruction above.

Comment: I know how a master Detail work, This work if I get data directly from DataBase Tables, but when I send list to Report not works properly.

Comment: The Data Sources and Business Objects work different.